# How to understand gsub(/^.*\//, '') or the regex

Tags: ruby, regex, gsub

Breaking up the below code to understand my regex and `gsub` understanding:

```
str = "abc/def/ghi.rb"
str = str.gsub(/^.*\//, '')
#str = ghi.rb
```

`^` : beginning of the string

`\/` : escape character for `/`

`^.*\/` : everything from beginning to the last occurrence of `/` in the string

Is my understanding of the expression right?

How does `.*` work exactly?

Comment: Actually, `^` is the anchor for begin of line. Begin of string is `\A`. For single-line strings, both work the same.

Comment: Nothing wrong with your regex, but `File.basename(str)` might be more appropriate.

Comment: This is well documented around the internet and in the Regexp documentation. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your general understanding is correct. The entire regex will match `abc/def/` and `String#gsub` will replace it with empty string.

However, note that [`String#gsub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/String.html#method-i-gsub) doesn't change the string in place. This means that `str` will contain the original value(`"abc/def/ghi.rb"`) after the substitution. To change it in place, you can use [`String#gsub!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/String.html#method-i-gsub-21).

---

As to how `.*` works - the algorithm the regex engine uses is called [backtracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking). Since `.*` is greedy (will try to match as many characters as possible), you can think that something like this will happen:

> **Step 1**: `.*` matches the entire string `abc/def/ghi.rb`. Afterwards `\/` tries to match a forward slash, but fails (nothing is left to match). `.*` has to backtrack.
>   **Step 2**: `.*` matches the entire string except the last character - `abc/def/ghi.r`. Afterwards `\/` tries to match a forward slash, but fails (`/ != b`). `.*` has to backtrack.
>   **Step 3**: `.*` matches the entire string except the last two characters - `abc/def/ghi.`. Afterwards `\/` tries to match a forward slash, but fails (`/ != r`). `.*` has to backtrack.
>   **...**
>   **Step n**: `.*` matches `abc/def`. Afterwards `\/` tries to match a forward slash and succeeds. The matching ends here.

Comment: If the steps in quoted formatting are from another site or person, it's important to give proper attribution to them. If they're not quoted from another or person, then using quoting is the wrong format used.

Comment: @theTinMan, I see quoting often times used for other things (like long lines of logs). If you have a suggestion on how the entire block of text can look as if it is in different highlighting while at the same time leaves me with the option to **bold** and `code` inside I will use that.

Comment: Even long logs shouldn't be quoted. People use that because it forces wrapping, rather than extract the bare minimum necessary to demonstrate the problem, so don't emulate that thinking. Is it necessary to change the background color? Quoting does that to call out it's from another source. If it's your content then allow it to be the normal background and use the existing formatting for numbered lists. That way, *when* they change the CSS for the site, the information fits the look and feel, not what you thought it should have been a particular day.

Comment: @theTinMan, so you offer no alternative. You have to understand that people will use quoting for practical purposes given no other option. For example, this answer would be a lot less readable if it was all in white background. And sometimes people can't extract the essential information in their log and that is the point of their question. Should logs never be used in questions?

Comment: There are alternates, it's just people don't want to believe those work. The vast majority of the site uses very simple formatting and it works nicely. The guidelines specify to reduce input information to the minimum necessary, and almost every log can be reduced greatly to provide the necessary information. That people don't reduce is more an example that they didn't want to expend the effort to figure out what is essential. But that's a different topic that's often discussed on [meta].

Answer (score 2):

No, not quite.

- `^`: beginning of a line
- `\/`: escaped slash (escape character is `\` alone)
- `^.*\/` : everything from beginning of a line to the last occurrence of `/` in the string

`.*` depends on the mode of the regex. In singleline mode (i.e., without `m` option), it means the longest possible sequence of zero or more non-newline characters. In multiline mode (i.e., with `m` option), it means the longest possible sequence of zero or more characters.

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is correct, but you should also note that the last statement is true because:

```
Repetition is greedy by default: as many occurrences as possible 
are matched while still allowing the overall match to succeed.
```

Quoted from the [Regexp](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Regexp.html) documentation.

Comment: Rather than say "here" for anchor text, provide something a bit more useful. See http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/noClickHere and http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG10-HTML-TECHS/#link-text for explanations why.

Comment: @theTinMan thank you for the advice. I believe it is useful and I will try to follow it in my future posts.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. In short, it matches any number of any characters (`.*`) ending with a literal `/` (`\/`).

`gsub` replaces the match with the second argument (empty string `''`).

Answer (score 0):

> Nothing wrong with your regex, but File.basename(str) might be more appropriate.

To expound on what @Stefen said: It really looks like you're dealing with a file path, and that makes your question an XY problem where you're asking about Y when you should ask about X: Rather than how to use and understand a regex, the question should be what tool is used to manage paths.

Instead of rolling your own code, use code already written that comes with the language:

```
str = "abc/def/ghi.rb"
File.basename(str) # => "ghi.rb"
File.dirname(str) # => "abc/def"
File.split(str) # => ["abc/def", "ghi.rb"]
```

The reason you want to take advantage of File's built-in code is it takes into account the difference between directory delimiters in *nix-style OSes and Windows. At start-up, Ruby checks the OS and sets the `File::SEPARATOR` constant to what the OS needs:

```
File::SEPARATOR # => "/"
```

If your code moves from one system to another it will continue working if you use the built-in methods, whereas using a regex will immediately break because the delimiter will be wrong.