# Regex with Ruby gsub

Tags: ruby, regex, replace, gsub

My goal is to replace spaces and `"/"` with `'-'` from the input:

```
name = "chard / pinot noir"
```

to get:

```
"chard-pinot-noir"
```

My first attempt is:

```
name.gsub(/ \/\ /, '-') #=> "chart-pinot noir"
```

My second attempt is:

```
name.gsub(/\/\s+/, '-') #=> "chard -pinot noir"
```

My third attempt is:

```
name.gsub(/\s+/, '-') #=> "chard-/-pinot-noir"
```

[This article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34395026/how-to-understand-gsub-or-the-regex?rq=1) helped. The first group checks for a forward slash `/`, and contains a break. The second portion replaces a forward slash with `'-'`. However, the space remains. I believe `/s` matches spaces, but I can't get it to work while simultaneously checking for forward slash.

My question is how can I get the desired result, shown above, with varying strings using either regex or a ruby helpers. Is there a preferred way? Pro / Con ?

Comment: `name.gsub(/[\/\s]+/,'-') #=> "chard-pinot-noir"`

Comment: @SagarPandya thank you! the docs on regex are confusing. is the `+/` regex for checking all forward slashes? put as answer and i can report as answered.

Comment: `[\/\s]+` checks for one or more of any of `/` or whitespace characters. [Rublar](http://www.rubular.com/) has a nice cheatsheet if you want to play.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't know much about [regex](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Regexp.html), you can do this way.

```
name = "chard / pinot noir"
(name.split() - ["/"]).join("-")
=> "chard-pinot-noir"
```

I think the best way is use with [regex](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Regexp.html) as  [@Sagar Pandya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5101493/sagar-pandya) described above.

```
name.gsub(/[\/\s]+/,'-')
=> "chard-pinot-noir"
```